# Querying the Model in Ember JS

Tags: ember.js

I have a model called *Game* in Ember. To access all the games I run

```
this.store.query('game').
```

Now, I would like to retrieve all the "upcoming games" how should I go about this?

- Do I create a sub class of model Game.
- Can I created a static method on Game e.g Game.getUpcoming?
- Do I have to pass a filter to the Game

Thanks!

Comment: SideNote: to access all the model you can use `this.store.findAll('game')` instead of query.

Comment: Right, but I want to query say game:upcoming. findAll('game') would just return all the games right ?

Comment: Yes. you are right. But in your question you mentioned you are using query for returning all games. Here is what you mentioned `To access all the games I run this.store.query('game').`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to Game model

```
isUpcoming: DS.attr('boolean')
```

and when querying in routes

```
this.store.query("game", {filter: {isUpcoming: true}});
```

No need to overcomplicate things.

Comment: Hmmm, I was thinking on the similar lines. Thanks!